# How do I combine addvspace and nobreak?

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

`\nobreak` seems to break `\addvspace`, as shown by the example below.  **How can I prevent a page break before and after a space added by `addvspace`, without breaking `addvspace`?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
No breaks:
\par{}\nobreak\addvspace{5em} \nobreak\addvspace{5em} \nobreak\addvspace{5em}
\par{}(ends here)

With breaks:
\par{}\addvspace{5em} \addvspace{5em} \addvspace{5em}
\par{}(ends here)
\end{document}
```

Here's is a more concrete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\block}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\par{}Here's a block
\par\addvspace{4em}\nobreak\block % Does not work

\clearpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\par{}Here's a block
\par\nobreak\addvspace{4em}\block % Works, but…
\subsection*{Here's a second block}
\par\nobreak\addvspace{4em}\block % … addvspace behaves as vspace
\end{document}
```

In this example, I have a block of text (`\block`) preceded by a single sentence. I want to keep them together.  Additionally, I want block to be visually separated from its surroundings, by a consistent amount of vertical space.  I use `addvspace` before each `\block` to ensure this.

Unfortunately, `\nobreak` confuses vspace: the space following section titles is not combined with the space preceding blocks.

How can I ensure that `\block` is always preceded by `5em` of vertical space, while preventing page breaks before blocks, and without adding spurious space between section titles and immediately following blocks?

Comment: not directly addressing your problem, but multiple consecutive instances of `\addvspace` aren't really going to add up to the expected total.  the total will only be the largest value specified with either the `\addvspace`s or the vertical space already present at that point.  `\addvspace` is an instruction to bring the total space to the specified value, not to accumulate it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Exactly: hence my question. This behaviour is what I expect, but the `\nobreak` call breaks it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\addpenalty` which is similar to `\addvspace`, but for penalties.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\block}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\par{}Here's a block
\par\addpenalty{10000}\addvspace{4em}\block  Does not work

\clearpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\par{}Here's a block
\par\addpenalty{10000}\addvspace{4em}\block % Works, but…
\subsection*{Here's a second block}
\par\addpenalty{10000}\addvspace{4em}\block % … addvspace behaves as vspace
\end{document}
```